# Many programs writing/reading one file?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, streamreader, streamwriter

I am writing a messaging app in C# that runs on a shared file server on a network. The program works by multiple users running the program which accesses a file that is shared between the multiple computers. Hence, I need to use the StreamReader/StreamWriter to access the file with multiple programs at once (EDIT: I now know this isn't a good way to do it, but it's what I needed at the time). So how may I access a single file with multiple programs without getting errors about the file being in use?

Comment: Sorry, but **to me** is not very clear a relation between the file and chat messages.

Comment: I think you should reconsider your desing about `many programs writing/reading one file`, since it is not the way to go.

Comment: The file is where the chat messages are stored. @L.B how else can I have many people that can see these messages at one time. And when they are viewing the messages, its going to be refreshing every few seconds, any suggestions?

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: You should use a database. That's what they're for.

Comment: `how else can I have many people that can see these messages at one time.` Do you think other coders do it your way? And yes I have too many suggestions, but is hard to summarize in a few sentences. If you ask a specific question, I'd be glad to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach will lead to problems in the future. I'd consider leveraging Redis pub/sub if I were you.

But, since you asked... (I wrote a blog post on this: http://procbits.com/2011/02/18/streamwriter-share-read-access-in-another-process/ )

Generator of chat data:

```
var fs = File.Open(@"C:\messages.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw.AutoFlush = true;
```

Somewhere else in your app or another app...

Readers of chat data:

```
var fs = File.Open(@"C:\messages.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
var sr = new StreamReader(fs);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need single file where multiple users/programs/entites.. shoud read/write without disturbing each other, I would suggest to consider (among other solutions) an use of [Sqlite](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22165/Using-SQLite-in-your-C-Application) like a simple DB backend. No installation or service setup needed. Just use `C#` dlls of it and, basically, according to your requests, you will get what you need.

One user writes in the `db file` (INSERT) another can read (SELECT) from it.

Comment: Do I use System.Data.Sql for that?

Comment: @EfeOzturkoglu: no, you need to reference it's `DLL`, tha can be downloaded from the `Sqlite` site.

Comment: @EfeOzturkoglu: the download page for `.NET` binaries is here: [Sqlite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think twice about using a text file as a means of a communication peer.
It's like asking for trouble.

Please take a look at using a P2P solution instead:
[Peer Channel Chat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751502.aspx)
[A simple peer to peer chat application using WCF netPeerTcpBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17321/A-simple-peer-to-peer-chat-application-using-WCF-n)

That will give you a much more fitting architecture for your requirements.

Comment: That seems like a good solution, but I already wrote alot of code to work with the text file

Comment: A high number of LOC doesn't necessarily justify the chosen method.

Comment: fine, ill take another look at it